# Не устанавливается cookie из данныx, что вернул mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, cookie

Есть два кода, первый не рабочий, данные берутся с БД, второй - аналог, беру данные с массива, работает? Есть варианты по первому?

Код c mysql:

```
session_start();
$db->conn_open();
$ses = session_id(); 
// где $db->q - mysql_query
$ses_db = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ses` = '".$ses."'");
$ses_d = mysql_fetch_array($ses_db);
$ses_data = $ses_d;
$cookie_dn = mb_strtolower($ses_data["q_name"], "utf-8");
$cookie_dv = $ses_data['q_answ'];
$retr = setcookie("question[".$cookie_dn."]",$cookie_dv,time()+1000000);
var_dump($retr); // false
var_dump($cookie_dn); // validated
var_dump($cookie_dv); // validated
var_dump($_COOKIE["question"]); // NULL
die;
```

Код класса БД:

```
$db = new database;
class database {
    var $dblink;
    function conn_open() {
        global $wdb;
        $this->dblink = mysql_connect($wdb['host'], $wdb['username'], $wdb['password']);
        mysql_select_db($wdb['name']);
        @mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    }
    function q($query) {
            return mysql_query($query);
        }
}
```

Код без mysql:

```
session_start();
$db->conn_open();
$ses = session_id(); 
$ses_d = array("val"=>"1", "val2"=>"2");
$ses_data = $ses_d;
$cookie_dn = mb_strtolower($ses_data["q_name"], "utf-8");
$cookie_dv = $ses_data['q_answ'];
$retr = setcookie("question[".$cookie_dn."]",$cookie_dv,time()+1000000);
var_dump($retr); // true
var_dump($cookie_dn); // validated
var_dump($cookie_dv); // validated
var_dump($_COOKIE["question"]); // validated
die;
```

Comment: Вы в первом коде просто вывести в браузер пробовали данные, которые получаете запросом из БД? Они приходят?

Comment: @n.osennij, да там где стоит " // validated ", данные приходят корректные, но первый вариант куку не ставит, второй - легко.

Comment: "Есть два кода, первый не рабочий, данные берутся с БД, второй - аналог, беру данные с массива, работает? Есть варианты по первому?"

Так что вы у нас спрашиваете? Вы правильно расставили все знаки вопросов и др?

Comment: @n.osennij, я не могу понять, запрос к базе адекватный, ответ адекватный, куки не ставятся, в чем может быть проблема. Аналогичные форумы прочитал, кука перед выводом данных в браузер, все правильно. Повторю вопрос, почему он не работает, кто то сталкивался с подобной нелепостью?

Comment: Если перед вызовом функции клиенту уже передавался какой-либо вывод (тэги, пустые строки, пробелы, текст и т.п.), setcookie() вызовет отказ и вернет FALSE. Если setcookie() успешно отработает, то вернет TRUE. Это, однако, не означает, что клиентское приложение (броузер) правильно приняло и обработало cookie.

Comment: Соответственно ищи эти пробелы и пусты строки перед открывающим тегом php. Обычно нотис должен вылезать по этому поводу, но мало ли как у тебя там настроено. Других причин я не вижу.

Comment: @JohnSmitConor, с каких пор куки стали видны на той же странице? `После передачи клиенту cookie станут доступны через массив $_COOKIE при следующей загрузке страницы.` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

И уберите из имени куки []. Попробуйте.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    //устанавливаем соедиение c БД тут в $connection

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ses = '$ses'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) {die($connection->error);};
    $myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $cookie_dn = mb_strtolower($myrow['q_name'], 'utf-8');
    $cookie_dv = $myrow['q_answ'];
    $cookie_name="question_${cookie_dn}";
    $retr=setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_dv, time()+1000000, '/');

    var_dump($retr);
    echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но у меня php 5.3 и код на mysql, ваш вариант не пропустило. А ошибкой было то, что в ['q_name'] текст был с пробелами, через str_replace() пропустил, все заработало.